# SDO_GEOMETRY queries

Tags: oracle-spatial

I have  tables in my Oracle database: AIRPORTS and POPULATED_PLACES. Both two tables were transformed to SRID 3426 and spatial indexes were created as well as USER_SDO_GEOM_METADATA table.

AIRPORT has ICAO (PK), NAME, CITY, LOCATION (geometry).

POPULATED_PLACE has CGNDB_ID (PK), GEO_NAME (ref. CITY), CENTROID (geometry)

I want to answer these questions: Which populated place has the most airports within 20 km and what are the airports within 20 km of this place?

I wrote this query:

```sql
WITH airport_distances AS (
  SELECT
    pp.GEO_NAME,
    a.ICAO,
    a.NAME AS airport_name,
    SDO_GEOM.SDO_DISTANCE(pp.CENTROID, a.LOCATION, 0.005, 'unit=METER') AS distance
  FROM
    AIRPORT a
    JOIN POPULATED_PLACE pp ON a.CITY = pp.GEO_NAME
      AND a.IATA IS NOT NULL
      AND pp.CODE IS NOT NULL
      AND a.ICAO IS NOT NULL
),
airports_within_20km AS (
  SELECT
    GEO_NAME,
    ICAO,
    airport_name
  FROM
    airport_distances
  WHERE
    distance <= 20000
),
populated_place_ranked AS (
  SELECT
    GEO_NAME,
    COUNT(*) AS num_airports
  FROM
    airports_within_20km
  GROUP BY
    GEO_NAME
  ORDER BY
    num_airports DESC
  FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY
)

SELECT
  ppr.GEO_NAME AS city,
  ppr.num_airports AS total_airports,
  aw.ICAO AS airport_ICAO,
  aw.airport_name
FROM
  populated_place_ranked ppr
  JOIN airports_within_20km aw ON ppr.GEO_NAME = aw.GEO_NAME
ORDER BY
  aw.airport_name ASC;
```

The issue is that I get 0 rows selected. I tried to load the data again as AIRPORTS is loaded in srid 4326 but POPULATED_PLACE is in SRID 4269 so I transformed it manually to 4326 and updated metadata and index afterwards. I am not sure what's the issue at the moment.

Comment: One important point to remember. While the spatial **operators** (`sdo_contains()`, `sdo_within_distance()` etc.) work with any combination of coordinate systems, the **functions** (`sdo_geom.sdo_distance()`, etc) all require that, when using multiple geometry objects, that all are in the *same coordinate system*. This means that your distance calculation will fail (= throw an exception) when the SRID of the two geometries involved are different.

Comment: You said you transformed your data so that both AIRPORTS and POPULATED PLACES are now in the same SRID, but you still do not get any result ?

Comment: About the query: are you sure the CITY column of AIRPORTS is the same as GEO_NAME of POPULATED_PLACES ? Matching strings can be fraud with trouble. For example, one may be upper case, while the other is not. Same for dashes or other separators or abbreviations. I would run this query in stages. Just the first one will indicate whether your core going works correctly.